# Is an epimorphic endomorphism of a noetherian commutative ring necessarily an isomorphism?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, noetherian, epimorphisms

Let $A$ be noetherian commutative ring with one, and let $f:A\to A$ be an epimorphic endomorphism of $A$.

> Is $f$ necessarily an isomorphism?

("An epimorphic endomorphism" means of course "an endomorphism which is an epimorphism". In this post "ring" means "commutative ring with one", and morphisms are required to map $1$ to $1$.)

---

A few reminders:

A morphism of rings $f:A\to B$ is an **epimorphism** if for all pairs of morphisms $(g,h):B\rightrightarrows C$ the equality $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$. Surjective morphisms are epimorphic, but the converse does not hold: for instance the inclusion $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ *is* an epimorphism.

If $A$ is noetherian and  $f:A\to A$ is a **surjective** endomorphism, then $f$ is an isomorphism, because if $f$ were not injective, then the kernels of the iterated  endomorphisms $f^n$ would form an ascending chain of ideals of $A$.

If $A$ is a nonzero ring, then the map $(a_1,a_2,\dots)\to(a_2,a_3,\dots)$ is a surjective endomorphism of $B:=A\times A\times\cdots$ which is not an isomorphism (but of course $B$ is not noetherian).

---

A few links:

MathOverflow thread [What do epimorphisms of (commutative) rings look like?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109/461).

Stacks Project Section [Epimorphisms of rings](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM).

[Samuel Seminar](http://www.numdam.org/issues/SAC_1967-1968__2_/) . See in particular Section 2 of Exposé Number 7 by Daniel Ferrand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. For instance, let $A=\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1},(x+1)^{-1},(x+2)^{-1},\dots]$.  Then $A$ is Noetherian, since it is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Now consider the homomorphism $f:A\to A$ which maps $x$ to $x+1$.  The image of $f$ is $B=\mathbb{Z}[x,(x+1)^{-1},(x+2)^{-1},\dots]$ and in particular $f$ is not surjective since the image does not contain $x^{-1}$.  But $f$ is epimorphic, since $A$ is a localization of $B$ (just invert $x$).