# Are epimorphic endomorphisms of noetherian commutative rings always injective?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, noetherian

[In this post "ring" means "commutative ring with one".]

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring, and let $f:A\to A$ be an endomorphism which is also an epimorphism.

> Is $f$ necessarily injective?

Eric Wofsey gave an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3376063/660) of an epimorphic endomorphism of a noetherian ring which is not surjective. (It is well known, and easy to prove, that *surjective* endomorphisms of noetherian rings are automatically bijective.)

[By definition, a morphism of rings $f:A\to B$ is an **epimorphism** if for all pairs of morphisms $(g,h):B\rightrightarrows C$ the equality $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$. Surjective morphisms are epimorphic, but the converse does not always hold: for instance the inclusion $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ *is* an epimorphism.]

---

For more details about epimorphisms see

$\bullet$ MathOverflow thread [What do epimorphisms of (commutative) rings look like?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109/461).

$\bullet$ Stacks Project Section [Epimorphisms of rings](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM).

$\bullet$ [Samuel Seminar](http://www.numdam.org/issues/SAC_1967-1968__2_/) .

$\bullet$ MathOverflow thread [Is Krull dimension non-increasing along ring epimorphisms?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/52197/461).

Comment: Maybe worth noting that epimorphic endomorphisms of Artinian rings are always isomorphisms, so don't look there.

Comment: @BadamBaplan - Thanks for your interesting comment! The reference I know for the fact you mention is [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/101552/461) of Steven Landsburg. (The comments to Steven's answer helped me understand the answer.) You have perhaps another reference and/or proof. If so, what is it?

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/344427/461